# R: Export a series of plots that can be flipped through using arrow keys

Tags: r

I want to export a series of plots (either plotly, or rAmCharts or some other package) that can be flipped through quickly using arrow keys, instead of saving down multiple files or having all the plots in sequence in an rmarkdown doc. Is there a standard way of doing this in R?

Comment: Can you describe more what is deficient if you have them in sequence in an rmarkdown doc? A slide deck with rmarkdown's Presentation-PowerPoint option, or `officer`'s output to PowerPoint, or an html format like `xaringan` would give you the ability to move through slides using the arrow keys.